# Как получить доступ к массиву не зная ключа?

Tags: javascript

Привет. Как получить доступ к массиву значений в JSON-объекте не зная ключа?

```
{
    "48":{
        "flights_baggage":[
            [
                "",
                ""
            ]
        ],
        "url":4800000,
        "currency":"rub",
        "price":145988,
        "unified_price":145988
    }
}
```

В данном объекте ключ объекта `48`. Но он постоянно меняется.

Comment: Перебирайте https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration Хотя наверное лучше https://learn.javascript.ru/object-for-in

Comment: ключ всегда только один?

Comment: @Sergiks да, но он меняется. Может быть 48, может быть 122, может 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Предлагаю вот такой вариант:

```js
var arg = {
    "48":{
        "flights_baggage":[
            [
                "",
                ""
            ]
        ],
        "url":4800000,
        "currency":"rub",
        "price":145988,
        "unified_price":145988
    }
};

for(var key in arg){
  console.log(arg[key])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно через Object.keys

```js
var obj = {
    "48": {
        "flights_baggage": [
            [
                "",
                ""
            ]
        ],
        "url": 4800000,
        "currency": "rub",
        "price": 145988,
        "unified_price": 145988
    }
};

console.log(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вначале парсите данные JSON:

```
result = JSON.parse(result);
```

Далее поочередно перебираете все значения:

```
result.forEach(function(data, index) {
    ...
});
```

Где `index` и будет требуемый ключ.

Comment: а него в корне объект, а не массив, поэтому forEach не подойдет

Comment: @Grundy да, тогда надо предварительно сконвертировать или выполнять for (key in obj)

Answer (score 0):

Можно перебрать все ключи объекта с помощью `for( x in object)`:

```js
function getData(s) {
  var key, data, record, result=[];
  try{ data = JSON.parse(s)} catch(e){ console.log(e);return []; }
  for( key in data) {
    record = data[key];
    result.push( "" + record.price + " "+ record.currency);
  }
  return result;
}

var jsonData = '{"48":{ "flights_baggage":[["",""]], "url":4800000, "currency":"rub", "price":145988, "unified_price":145988}}';

document.body.innerHTML = getData(jsonData).join("<br>");
```